# .submit() open two tabs instead of one

Tags: jquery, tabs, submit, attr

```
("#preview").click(function() {
     $("form").attr({action: "preview.php", target: "_blank"}).submit();
  });
```

When click on the `<input type="button" id="preview" />` I want to submit the preview to an other page. 
The thing is, it is working but jquery open 2 times the same tab.

Thank you for your help

Comment: please create a fiddle .

Answer (score 1):

try `return false;` end of click event to prevent submitting the form again

```
$("#preview").click(function() {
    $("form").attr({action: "http://www.google.fr", target: "_blank"}).submit();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
  $("#preview").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $("form").attr({action: "preview.php", target: "_blank"}).submit();
     });
```

edit:

I mean:

```
$("#preview").click(function(e) {

    $("form").attr({action: "preview.php", target: "_blank"}).submit();
});

$("form").submit(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem... Which was not really one because of my mistake !

I forgot but on an include file, there was an other form (search bar)... And because I use ("form"), jQuery submit both.

Thank you all for your time and answer !